# How to convert a string of coma separated characters to a string of strings with each string in single quotes and separated by comma

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string

```
"#72c02c, #3498db, #e67e22, #9c8061, #4765a0, #79d5b3"
```

I want to convert it to the following:

```
"'#72c02c', '#3498db', '#e67e22', '#9c8061', '#4765a0', '#79d5b3'"
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: So you need to split on commas, and join using `', '` as a separator and `'` as the prefix and suffix. What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is typically much more useful when you show the progress you've already made...

Comment: Just a hint for you `String [] chars = testString.split(,);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why everyone is using regex... this needs only a simple text replace:

```
str = "'" + str.replace(", ", "', '") + "'";
```

This just puts quotes before/after commas and puts a quote at each end, which is easy to understand.

Comment: You beated me! I was writing the same answer... So I won't post mine and upvote yours instead :)

Comment: @thanks, I had tried a replaceAll(",", "','"), but dint work, this worked,

Comment: @Bohemian, what if we want to double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: Then do this: `str = '"' + str.replace(", ", "\", \"") + '"';`

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "#72c02c, #3498db, #e67e22, #e74c3c, #ecf0f1, #9b6bcc, #27d7e7, #9c8061, #4765a0, #79d5b3";

            s = s.replaceAll("(#|,)","'$1");
            if (s.charAt(s.length()-1) != ',')
                    s = s + "'";
```

Might not be the most elegant solution, but it handles the case of the final item in the string not ending with a `,`. Will work if it does happen to end in a comma too.

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to operate with it as with the simple String object instance, the you can do it with regex `([#\w]+)` and `String.replaceAll()` method, like:

```
String testString = "#72c02c, #3498db, #e67e22, #e74c3c, #ecf0f1, #9b6bcc, #27d7e7, #9c8061, #4765a0, #79d5b3";
System.out.println(testString.replaceAll("([#\\w]+)","'$1'"));
```

Where with `([#\w]+)`, you just take every group of alpha-numeric characters or `#`

Then you just replace it with `'$1'`, where `$1` is the whole group, which was found.

Comment: Use the 2 regex becasue the first will fail to quote last string. hence no , after last elment

Comment: @PetterFriberg was wrong, thanks for the remark. deleted the first one